# If I have no data to share with other applications, shall I still need to use Content Provider API?

Tags: android

What's the purpose of Content Provider? The document [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) said:

> Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications.

I just want to store my data into Sqlite, no need to share with other application, shall I still need to use Content Provider API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite is an Android wrapper for using SQLite DB's. It provides neat and cleaner interface for all DB operations. Ofcourse one of the major pros for using Content providers is it provides mechanism for sharing your data with other apps.
But surely even for storing and retrieving data in db, Content provider provides a nice interface and it is highly recommended. 
There are other classes like SqliteDBHelper using which you can perform direct operations on DB.